# yii gridview filter with external api and one to many

Tags: php, yii2

I am struggling with gridview filter. In my code I have two getters.

```
public function getPhone()
{
    return UserPhone::find()->where(['user_id' => $this->id])->orderBy('updated_at DESC')->one();
}

public function getDevice()
{
    return ExternalAPiHelper::getDeviceInfo($this->id); // this will make a call to external db, and fetching result from there.
}
```

I am trying to do a filter for `$user->phone->country` and `$user->device->type` I am not sure how I can get the results from both of these in a clean manner. Currently, I am fetching the id from the above 2 and then using the result array in `$query->where(['in', 'id', $ids]);`

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **hasMany** or **hasOne** method for relation as per requirement

```
public function getPhone(){
    return $this->hasOne(UserPhone::className(),['user_id' => 'id'])
           ->orderBy('updated_at DESC');
}
```

than add this relation in main query where you want to apply filter

```
$query = ....Model query where you define above relations
$query->joinWith('phone')
$query->andWhere(['LIKE','country',$countryName])
```

[explore more about yii2 relations](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/780/drills-search-by-a-hasmany-relation-in-yii-2-0#relation)

Comment: I am getting this error,
Setting read-only property: common\models\UserSearch::phone

Comment: I missed public $phone in user search. It worked
Thanks @Shringiraj